# strncpy to already created char []

Tags: c++, class, char, strncpy

There is class

```
class Cow{
    char name[20];
    char* hobby;
    double weight;
public:
    [..]
    Cow & operator=(const Cow &c);
    [..]
};
```

and I'm wondering how to write definition of `operator=` method.
I wrote definition that equal to -

```
Cow & Cow::operator=(const Cow &c){
    if(this==&c)
        return *this;
    delete [] hobby;
    hobby=new char [strlen(c.hobby)+1];
    weight=c.weight;
    strncpy(name,c.name,20);
    return *this;
}
```

but what if there is already created name[20] with like "Philip Maciejowsky" and I strncpy to it "Adam". After operator=(...) will name equal to "adamlip Maciejowsky"?
How to fix it if it overwrites like that?

Comment: Incidentally, you forgot to copy `hobby`.

Comment: haha, you're so apprehensive :) good eye

Comment: `char name[20];` - No, not in c++.  If this isn't homework, change that to `std::string` and do the same for `char *hobby`

Comment: C++ Primer Plus's by Stephen Pratta excercise. I belive he knows what to do to teach me c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strcpy()` or add a null terminator after using `strncpy()`. `strncpy()` does not add the null terminator (`\0`), where as `strcpy()` does.

My advice: use `std::string` instead of `c-styled` null terminated string.

> when in rome, do the romans!

---

From http://cplusplus.com

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than >num (thus, in this case, destination may not be a null terminated C string).

Since `Adam` is lesser in length than `Philip Maciejowsky` - the `strncpy()` will NOT pad the remaining destination(that is `Philip Maciejowsky`) with `\0`. And hence the output looks like:

`Adamip Maciejowsky` - `strcpy()` or doing `memset(destination, 0, lengthOfDestination)` and then calling `strncpy()` will result in your output being `Adam` as well. Multiple ways to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Or if possible use std::string rather than old C style processing.

Comment: that is how I would do it @suspectus . since the OP wants to learn about C styled strings, <shrugs>. But I always say "when in rome, do the romans"

Comment: On my machine, the manpage for strncpy says that it null-fills the rest of the array it's copying to.

Comment: @medgno that's non-standard behavior. The standard says `strncpy()` **should not** nullterminate

Comment: From Cplusplus.com : No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num (thus, in this case, destination may not be a null terminated C string).

Comment: Right, I saw that bit, but thought that only means that you might want to set `name[NAME_SIZE-1] = 0` if you're really paranoid.  Otherwise, if the buffer has enough size for what you're copying, it'll be null-padded.  I think we might be strongly agreeing with each other. :)

Comment: If you want to guarantee that the string is always null-terminated, initialize `name[19]` to 0, and use `strncpy(name, c.name, 19);`

Comment: @medgno The issue is if you specify `NAME_SIZE` as the limit, it can overwrite the null-terminator with a character. So you have to use `NAME_SIZE-1` as the limit as well.

Comment: @Barmar, I would use `memset()` and clear the whole damn string :-P

Comment: `strcpy()` definitely should **not** be used, since it may cause a buffer overflow unless you check the length of the source first. Using a `string` is the best choice, otherwise use `strncpy()` with a limit of `(sizeof Cow.name)-1`.

Comment: how about `memcpy()`?? @Barmar - Historically, `memcpy()` has been reported to be faster than `strcpy()` and `strncpy()`(I distinctly remember reading an article about that)

Comment: @Aniket That's even more convoluted. Then the amount to copy is `min(NAME_SIZE-1, strlen(c.name)+1)`. This requires two passes through the source, one to get the length, and another to copy it.

Comment: `strncpy()` *may or may not* null-terminate the target array. It pads it with zero or more `'\0'` characters, depending on the length of the source string and the specified size of the target array.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, I clarified that in the bottom half of the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're using C++ you shouldn't be using C-style strings and should instead be using the class std::string which makes everything easier in every way.

Assuming you're required to use char* strings, strncpy takes care of this.  C-style string are null-terminated, meaning that a string such as `"test"` takes up five bytes.  The bytes are, in order, `{'t', 'e', 's', t', 0}`.  The zero (or null) byte serves as a marker that the end of the string has been reached.

From the manpage for strncpy on my system:

The following sets chararray to `abc\0\0\0`:

```
       char chararray[6];

       (void)strncpy(chararray, "abc", sizeof(chararray));
```

So this means that the string will contain `"adam\0\0\0\0\0\0\0[etc.]"` where `\0` represents the null byte.  String functions will stop processing when they read the first null (because, remember, with C-style strings, there's no way to know the length of the string without scanning through it looking for `\0`).